# PhoneGAP Build - Unsupported devices on Google Play

Tags: cordova, google-play, phonegap-build

When publishing the APK generated by PGB - Google Play says the App is "not supported" by 267 devices, including Google Nexus 7.

The config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.test"
    version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Test</name>

    <description>Test</description>

    <author href="http://www.test.com/" email="info@test.com">Test</author>

    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.5.0" />          <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="false" />          <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="false" />          <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

    <gap:plugin name="BarcodeScanner" />
    <gap:plugin name="GenericPush" />
    <gap:plugin name="GAPlugin" />

    <access origin="*" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

</widget>
```

Any idea how can that be solved?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the AndroidManifest.xml is the file you need to check. You should make sure that you add uses-feature and specify android:required="false" for items, such as camera that are not required for your app. I have add the following successfully to a Cordova/PhoneGap app to support a wider range of devices:

```
    <!-- support a wider range of devices by not requiring a camera, gps, microphone or phone -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.GPS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Also, you might check [Google Play excludes devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772245/google-play-excludes-devices) and other similar results for issues specific to Google Nexus 7.

Google indicates that the APK's Supported Devices list can be checked for app filtering (http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#google-play ): Confirm the app's filtering After you've uploaded the app to the Developer Console, check the APK's Supported Devices list to make sure that the app is not filtered from tablet devices that you want to target.